# Roulette Probability playing 200 times

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a probability question that I've answered and want to know if I'm correct or where I went wrong:

> Play roulette 200 times, betting $1 each time:
>   Option A: Betting on Odd or Even
>   Option B: Betting on a Single Number

**1. P[win $\$40$ or more] - which option is better (A or B or same)**

Expected Roulette Value:

Odd or Even
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
+1 & -1\\\hline
\dfrac{18}{38} & \dfrac{20}{38}\\
+$18 & -$20
\end{array}\\E=-$2$$

Betting on Single Number
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
+1 & -1\\\hline
\dfrac1{38} & \dfrac{37}{38}\\
+$35 & -$37
\end{array}\\E=-$2$$

So obviously the expected value of both single number and even/odd (as well as every other category on the roulette board) is $-2$…

$$\begin{align}
\text{SD(Single Number)} &= 5.763\\
\text{Variance} &= 33.21\\[10pt]
\text{SD(Even/Odd)} &= .999\\
\text{Variance} &= .997\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\text{E(Playing 200 times)} &= 200(-2) &= -400\\
\text{SD(Single Number and Playing 200 Times)} &= \sqrt{200(33.21)} &= 81.50\\
\text{SD(Even/Odd and Playing 200 Times)} &= \sqrt{200(.997)} &= 14.12
\end{align}$$

Single Number:
$$z=\frac{40-(-2)}{81.50}=\frac{42}{81.50}=0.515\\
z(.52)=.69847=70\%$$

And the $z$-score is only the left side of the graph (correct?) so it would be $100\%-70\% = 30\%$ chance you win $\$40$ or more?

Even/Odd:
$$z=\frac{40-(-2)}{14.12}=\frac{42}{14.12}=2.974\\
z(2.97)=.99851=99.9\%$$

So only $0.1\%$ to win $\$40$ or more on even/odd?

**2. P[lose $\$40$ or more]**

Isn't this just the inverse of the last? So if you have a $30\%$ chance of winning $40+$, you will lose $40+$ $70\%$ of the time?

And then for the even/odd its $99.9\%$ of the time you lose $\$40$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since this was posted a few hours ago, are you in Dr. Wang's class? I'm also trying to see if I did right, but I can't find much about it. I did it the same way as you at first, but I realized that since in both cases you have independent events with only two possible outcomes (win/lose) they might be binomial distributions, so E(X)=np and SD(X)=sqrt(npq). Would really appreciate any insight anyone has, because I'm genuinely unsure of when to apply which equation and my teacher has a hard time communicating ideas in English. Gonna edit this really quickly, as I was reading ov

Comment: With either kind of bet you lose at the same rate. The house pays as if there were 36 possibilities, but there are actually 38.